# Advantages of subtyping over typeclasses

Tags: oop, scala, programming-languages, haskell, functional-programming

What are the advantages of <strike>OOP</strike> subtyping over typeclasses, if any? In other words, now that we have typeclasses, is there any reason to still use <strike>OOP</strike> subtyping?

PS: I am a Scala programmer.

Comment: @JoshD: I can find no relation whatsoever between those two questions, let alone consider them duplicates.

Comment: At least shorten that to "WTF" - wouldn't it make many people feel tainted and quesy having to participate in such form of conversation? Secondly, it appears you already know the answer. If so, please answer your own question so that folks like me could get properly educated.

Comment: @Blessed Geek: Sorry, couldn't control it. @JoshD: I am not asking for a side-by-side comparison. My question basically is: Now that we have typeclasses, is there any reason to still use OOP?

Comment: I think that instead of using the catch-all / umbrella term "OOP" it would be preferable to phrase this in terms of specific language characteristics.

Comment: @Randall: Rephrased as per your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: This question is very subjective and cannot be answered. Vote to close. Try asking here: http://bit.ly/ProgrammersQA

Comment: @OscarRyz: I believe this question can be answered objectively. Also, I don't think that is an appropriate site for this kind of question. Please don't misuse your power of closing the questions. Peace.

Comment: Aww ... c'mon - stop exercising your close-minded close privs already. I want to read answers to this question. C'MON!!!

Comment: The question is objective and can be answered. The capabilities of type classes and inheritance can be mathematically assessed. As far as I can read, Jim isn't asking for opinions. However, Jim, you could improve the writing: instead of asking for "reasons", ask if there's anything you can do with subtyping that you can't with type classes. Also, I'd speak of inheritance instead of subtyping, though that would change scope a bit and may not be what you mean at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At present, the syntactic overhead of Scala type classes is a good bit larger than for subtyping via trait inheritance, as is the potential runtime overhead.  Imagine a case where you need to have fifty different types of events conform to an interface to support an event processing engine.  Much easier to write

```
class MyEvent extends Event{
  val name = "foo"
}
```

than

```
class MyEvent{
   val name = "foo"
}

object MyEvent2Event{
   implicit def convert(myEvent:MyEvent) = new Event{ val name = myEvent.name}
}
```

The second form allows a lot more flexibility in terms of post-hoc polymorphism, freedom of naming, and general bad-assery, but typing out those fifty conversion methods and then doing the appropriate imports when the typeclass is needed is going to get to be a right pain.  If you don't need the flexibility, it's tough to see the payoff.  Plus there's that nagging "new" keyword in the second, which will spawn endless "is this overstressing the garbage-collector" arguments.

The situation is worse for mixin inheritance that introduces mutable state.  Consider the following trait, taken from production code:

```
trait Locking{
   private val lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock()

   def withReadLock[T](body: => T):T={
      try{
         lock.readLock.lock()
         body
      }finally{
         lock.readLock.unlock()
      }
   }
   // same for withWriteLock
}
```

Incredibly handy use of mixin inheritance, and not really doable with Scala type classes, due to the presence of the "lock" val.  Where should it go? If you put it in the adapted class, you lose most of the encapsulation value of the trait.  If you put it in the adapter code, the locks no longer protect anything, since you'd be locking on different lock objects every time you're adapted.

Comment: Irrelevant aside Re:  "is this overstressing the garbage-collector" arguments: in this particular case, one could use 'lazy val' instead of 'def', right?

Comment: I don't believe so.  All of my "def"s have arguments, which means they can't be lazy vals.  Am I missing something?

Comment: oh, duh... sorry for posting before coffee ;)

Comment: Great explanation! I wonder if the first one could be a) easier to write with some syntactic sugar (something like 'typeclass MyEvent as Event {val name = "foo"} ') and b) then optimize the overhead away by the compiler.

Comment: Just an idea - having multiple imports could be solved to some extent by putting implicit conversions into traits and combining them to one single object that is then imported by callers. Something like
`trait MyEvent2Event { implicit def ... } ; ... object MyEventConversions extends MyEvent2Event with MyAnotherEvent2Event ... ;`.

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I find OOP easier to deal with within the constraints of what it handles well. In other words: in cases where you don’t actually *need* typeclasses, I find objects easier to understand.

However, this might just be an artifact of the syntactic overhead that the typical typeclass embedding of objects has. If Haskell had syntactic sugar for some common kinds of typeclass patterns, that difference would probably vanish.

What I find more interesting, is the fact that the Haskell community shows that typeclasses are more powerful than objects, since there exists a trivial embedding of objects in typeclasses, but typeclasses can do things objects can’t. The Scala community, however, shows that objects are at least as powerful as typeclasses<sup>1</sup>, since there exists a trivial embedding of typeclasses in objects.

This seems to indicate that the relationship between the two is much more intimate than commonly thought.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [*Type Classes as Objects and Implicits*](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/TypeClasses.pdf) by Bruno C.d.S. Oliveira, Adriaan Moors and Martin Odersky, as well as [the discussion of that paper on *Lambda the Ultimate*](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4039/), especially this nice summary by Paul Snively (emphasis added):

> Martin Odersky and team’s design decisions around how to do type classes in a unified OO and FP language continue to bear fascinating fruit. **Implicits look less and less like “poor man’s type classes,” and more and more like an improvement upon type classes**, in my opinion given a quick read of this paper.

Comment: Type classes can't do implementation inheritance, however.

Answer (score 7):

In a language that is not purely functional, subtyping lets you have different side-effects with the same usage; this isn't always easy to achieve with type classes.  (You can achieve it, of course; it just seems more awkward to me.)

Also, subtyping can be more efficient--it's a way to cache the information that "X is a Y" without requiring repeated conversion (or compiler heroics to cache that information) of X to Y.  For very deep hierarchies, this could possibly be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OOP_vs_type_classes

Comment: I have already seen that link. I am not asking for a side-by-side comparison. My question basically is: Now that we have typeclasses, is there any reason to still use OOP?

Comment: Apologies. Your original question wasn't clear to me; that one is much better.

Comment: I think type classes have been around for a while. Probably it is you who have just discover them. So the answer to your own question is completely up to you: Jim, now that you have discovered typeclasses, do **you** still need OOP?

Answer (score 3):

One more difference for Scala at least is that chains of subtypes just work, whereas chains of typeclasses are much tricker.  If we have types A, B, and C, then if A < B and B < C then necessarily A < C.  However, if A <% B and B <% C it is not necessarily the case that A <% C.  This is because the Scala compiler will not apply multiple implicit conversions, as otherwise type-inference because difficult and (IIRC) potentially undecideable.

Answer (score 2):

A pragmatic reason to continue support for OOP is interoperability. One of the currently ongoing questions in the BitC discussion is whether to add single inheritance to the language. There are pragmatic pros and cons, and also issues pro and con in its implications for the formal type system and type inference.

For a while, the instance resolution mechanism for type classes had us convinced that type classes were fundamentally flawed for lack of link safety. In the absence of a lexically scoped resolution mechanism, type class instance resolution fails to scale in human terms: a change by one development group can cause linkage errors in an application written in another place by a completely different group. That had us reluctantly looking at single inheritance and some form of F<sub><</sub>+SelfType sort of scheme. There are related concerns when instances have multiple resolutions with different degrees of specialization.

We have since come to an approach to instance resolution that looks to resolve this problem to our satisfaction. The question we are wrestling with now is (a) whether *BitC* programs need subtyping, and if so for what, and (b) even if we don't, whether interoperability with programs in OO languages may nonetheless require us to support a type system in which inheritance is expressible, and consequently a language in which it can be used.

None of which is any sort of conclusive answer to the OP's question. The point, I suppose, is that the issues here go beyond the design of any particular language. There are also human factors and interoperability concerns to be considered.

Jonathan Shapiro