# Impredicative types vs. plain old subtyping

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, subtype, impredicativetypes

A friend of mine posed a seemingly innocuous Scala language question last week that I didn't have a good answer to: whether there's an easy way to declare a collection of things belonging to some common typeclass.  Of course there's no first-class notion of "typeclass" in Scala, so we have to think of this in terms of traits and context bounds (i.e. implicits).

Concretely, given some trait `T[_]` representing a typeclass, and types `A`, `B` and `C`, with corresponding implicits in scope `T[A]`, `T[B]` and `T[C]`, we want to declare something like a `List[T[a] forAll { type a }]`, into which we can throw instances of `A`, `B` and `C` with impunity.  This of course doesn't exist in Scala; a [question last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213676/forall-in-scala) discusses this in more depth.

The natural follow-up question is "how does Haskell do it?"  Well, GHC in particular has a type system extension called [impredicative polymorphism](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#impredicative-polymorphism), described in the ["Boxy Types"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/boxy/boxy-icfp.pdf) paper.  In brief, given a typeclass `T` one can legally construct a list `[forall a. T a => a]`.  Given a declaration of this form, the compiler does some dictionary-passing magic that lets us retain the typeclass instances corresponding to the types of each value in the list at runtime.

Thing is, "dictionary-passing magic" sounds a lot like "vtables."  In an object-oriented language like Scala, subtyping is a much more simple, natural mechanism than the "Boxy Types" approach.  If our `A`, `B` and `C` all extend trait `T`, then we can simply declare `List[T]` and be happy.  Likewise, as Miles notes in a comment below, if they all extend traits `T1`, `T2` and `T3` then I can use `List[T1 with T2 with T3]` as an equivalent to the impredicative Haskell `[forall a. (T1 a, T2 a, T3 a) => a]`.

However, the main, well-known disadvantage with subtyping compared to typeclasses is tight coupling: my `A`, `B` and `C` types have to have their `T` behavior baked in.  Let's assume this is a major dealbreaker, and I *can't* use subtyping.  So the middle ground in Scala is pimps^H^H^H^H^Himplicit conversions: given some `A => T`, `B => T` and `C => T` in implicit scope, I can again quite happily populate a `List[T]` with my `A`, `B` and `C` values...

... Until we want `List[T1 with T2 with T3]`.  At that point, even if we have implicit conversions `A => T1`, `A => T2` and `A => T3`, we can't put an `A` into the list.  We could restructure our implicit conversions to literally provide `A => T1 with T2 with T3`, but I've never seen anybody do that before, and it seems like yet another form of tight coupling.

Okay, so my question finally is, I suppose, a combination of a couple questions that were previously asked here: ["why avoid subtyping?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266596/why-avoid-subtyping) and ["advantages of subtyping over typeclasses"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848492/advantages-of-subtyping-over-typeclasses) ... is there some unifying theory that says impredicative polymorphism and subtype polymorphism are one and the same?  Are implicit conversions somehow the secret love-child of the two?  And can somebody articulate a good, clean pattern for expressing multiple bounds (as in the last example above) in Scala?

Comment: Aah, sorry, missed that in first reading!

Comment: One thing I'm not clear about: if `List[T]` is an adequate (in context) translation for list `[forall a. T a => a]`, then why isn't `List[T1 with T2 with T3]` an adequate translation for list `[forall a. (T1 a, T2 a, T3 a) => a]`?

Comment: @MilesSabin thanks, that was unclear in my original post.  I've edited to clarify that I don't actually want to literally extend `T1`, `T2` and `T3` if I can use implicit conversions instead.  Also thank you for the opportunity to use the phrase "secret love-child" in a question about type systems on StackOverflow :)

Comment: `case class Instance[TC[_], A](a: A)(implicit val tc: TC[A]); List[Instance[Foo, _]](....)` ?

Comment: @retronym funny, i came up with much the same thing: https://gist.github.com/2026129#file_typeclasses.scala ... but couldn't figure out a nice way to extend it to support multiple typeclasses

Comment: So I have some sort of horrible bug in my Haskell examples: I can declare my list but can't put *anything* into it.  For example, `showlist :: [forall a. Show a => a]` ... `showlist = [()]` yields an error `Could not deduce (a ~ ()) from the context (Show a)`.  This has got to be the worst StackOverflow question ever.

Comment: @mergeconflict: What about using a GADT for this in Haskell, as in `data T where T :: Show a => a -> T`?  That will give you the behavior you want, except that you need to put a wrapper around each object to put it into the list.

Comment: I think you have impredicative polymorphism and existential qualification confused. The type `[forall a. Show a => a]` means a list of all types a such that `Show a`; `[()]` does not satisfy this type, since `()` is of the more specific type `()`. I'm not sure there are any values that satisfy this type, but it's not what you wanted anyway; to get what you wanted, you need an existential qualification which requires wrapping a new data constructor around it (although it doesn't *have* to be a GADT).

Comment: I believe what you're asking is not really what Scala's all about.         Even though Scala uses functional constructions, it's still OO at it's heart, so you should use subtyping. Your last example is confusing. You want an object of type T1 AND T2 AND T3. 'A' can be converted to T1, T2 or T3, but can you garantee that it can be converted to ALL three? I can't find a counterexample here, but it should not be hard to find that such constructions could allow unsound things. So in fact a implicit conversion to all three is needed to ensure soundness. Just my two cents.

Comment: @mithrandi If we had impredicative types but not existential quantification we could simulate the latter with something like `[forall r. (forall b. Show b => b -> r) -> r]`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're confusing impredicative types with existential types. Impredicative types allow you to put *polymorphic* values in a data structure, not arbitrary concrete ones. In other words `[forall a. Num a => a]` means that you have a list where each element works as any numeric type, so you can't put e.g. `Int` and `Double` in a list of type `[forall a. Num a => a]`, but you can put something like `0 :: Num a => a` in it. Impredicative types is not what you want here.

What you want is existential types, i.e. `[exists a. Num a => a]` (not real Haskell syntax), which says that each element is some unknown numeric type. To write this in Haskell, however, we need to introduce a wrapper data type:

```hs
data SomeNumber = forall a. Num a => SomeNumber a
```

Note the change from `exists` to `forall`. That's because we're describing the *constructor*. We can put any numeric type *in*, but then the type system "forgets" which type it was. Once we take it back out (by pattern matching), all we know is that it's some numeric type. What's happening under the hood, is that the `SomeNumber` type contains a hidden field which stores the type class dictionary (aka. vtable/implicit), which is why we need the wrapper type.

Now we can use the type `[SomeNumber]` for a list of arbitrary numbers, but we need to wrap each number on the way in, e.g. `[SomeNumber (3.14 :: Double), SomeNumber (42 :: Int)]`. The correct dictionary for each type is looked up and stored in the hidden field automatically at the point where we wrap each number.

The combination of existential types and type classes is in some ways similar to subtyping, since the main difference between type classes and interfaces is that with type classes the vtable travels separately from the objects, and existential types packages objects and vtables back together again.

However, unlike with traditional subtyping, you're not forced to pair them one to one, so we can write things like this which packages one vtable with two values of the same type.

```hs
data TwoNumbers = forall a. Num a => TwoNumbers a a

f :: TwoNumbers -> TwoNumbers
f (TwoNumbers x y) = TwoNumbers (x+y) (x*y)

list1 = map f [TwoNumbers (42 :: Int) 7, TwoNumbers (3.14 :: Double) 9]
-- ==> [TwoNumbers (49 :: Int) 294, TwoNumbers (12.14 :: Double) 28.26]
```

or even fancier things. Once we pattern match on the wrapper, we're back in the land of type classes. Although we don't know which type `x` and `y` are, we know that they're the same, and we have the correct dictionary available to perform numeric operations on them.

Everything above works similarly with multiple type classes. The compiler will simply generate hidden fields in the wrapper type for each vtable and bring them all into scope when we pattern match.

```hs
data SomeBoundedNumber = forall a. (Bounded a, Num a) => SBN a

g :: SomeBoundedNumber -> SomeBoundedNumber
g (SBN n) = SBN (maxBound - n)

list2 = map g [SBN (42 :: Int32), SBN (42 :: Int64)]
-- ==> [SBN (2147483605 :: Int32), SBN (9223372036854775765 :: Int64)]
```

As I'm very much a beginner when it comes to Scala, I'm not sure I can help with the final part of your question, but I hope this has at least cleared up some of the confusion and given you some ideas on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

@hammar's answer is perfectly right. Here is the scala way of doint it. For the example i'll take `Show` as the type class and the values `i` and `d` to pack in a list :

```
// The type class
trait Show[A] {
   def show(a : A) : String
}

// Syntactic sugar for Show
implicit final class ShowOps[A](val self : A)(implicit A : Show[A]) {
  def show = A.show(self)
}

implicit val intShow    = new Show[Int] {
  def show(i : Int) = "Show of int " + i.toString
}

implicit val stringShow = new Show[String] {
  def show(s : String) = "Show of String " + s
}


val i : Int    = 5
val s : String = "abc"
```

What we want is to be able run the following code

```
val list = List(i, s)
for (e <- list) yield e.show
```

Building the list is easy but the list won't "remember" the exact type of each of its elements. Instead it will upcast each element to a common super type `T`. The more precise super super type between `String` and `Int` being `Any`, the type of the list is `List[Any]`.

The problem is: what to forget and what to remember? We want to forget the exact type of the elements BUT we want to remember that they are all instances of `Show`. The following class does exactly that

```
abstract class Ex[TC[_]] {
  type t
  val  value : t
  implicit val instance : TC[t]
}

implicit def ex[TC[_], A](a : A)(implicit A : TC[A]) = new Ex[TC] {
  type t = A
  val  value    = a
  val  instance = A
}
```

This is an encoding of the existential :

```
val ex_i : Ex[Show] = ex[Show, Int](i)
val ex_s : Ex[Show] = ex[Show, String](s)
```

It pack a value with the corresponding type class instance.

Finally we can add an instance for `Ex[Show]`

```
implicit val exShow = new Show[Ex[Show]] {
  def show(e : Ex[Show]) : String = {
    import e._
    e.value.show 
  }
}
```

The `import e._` is required to bring the instance into scope. Thanks to the magic of implicits:

```
val list = List[Ex[Show]](i , s)
for (e <- list) yield e.show
```

which is very close to the expected code.