# Intersection of multiple implicit conversions: reinventing the wheel?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Okay, fair warning: this is a follow-up to my [ridiculous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732766/impredicative-types-vs-plain-old-subtyping) from last week.  Although I think this question isn't as ridiculous.  Anyway, here goes:

### Previous ridiculous question:

Assume I have some base trait `T` with subclasses `A`, `B` and `C`, I can declare a collection `Seq[T]` for example, that can contain values of type `A`, `B` and `C`. Making the subtyping more explicit, let's use the `Seq[_ <: T]` type bound syntax.

Now instead assume I have a typeclass `TC[_]` with members `A`, `B` and `C` (where "member" means the compiler can find some `TC[A]`, etc. in implicit scope). Similar to above, I want to declare a collection of type `Seq[_ : TC]`, using context bound syntax.

This isn't legal Scala, and attempting to emulate may make you feel like a [bad person](https://gist.github.com/2026129).  Remember that context bound syntax (when used correctly!) desugars into an implicit parameter list for the class or method being defined, which doesn't make any sense here.

### New premise:

So let's assume that typeclass instances (i.e. implicit values) are out of the question, and instead we need to use implicit conversions in this case.  I have some type `V` (the "v" is supposed to stand for "view," fwiw), and implicit conversions in scope `A => V`, `B => V` and `C => V`.  Now I can populate a `Seq[V]`, despite `A`, `B` and `C` being otherwise unrelated.

But what if I want a collection of things that are implicitly convertible both to views `V1` and `V2`?  I can't say `Seq[V1 with V2]` because my implicit conversions don't magically aggregate that way.

### Intersection of implicit conversions?

I solved my problem like this:

```
// a sort of product or intersection, basically identical to Tuple2
final class &[A, B](val a: A, val b: B)

// implicit conversions from the product to its member types
implicit def productToA[A, B](ab: A & B): A = ab.a
implicit def productToB[A, B](ab: A & B): B = ab.b

// implicit conversion from A to (V1 & V2)
implicit def viewsToProduct[A, V1, V2](a: A)(implicit v1: A => V1, v2: A => V2) =
  new &(v1(a), v2(a))
```

Now I can write `Seq[V1 & V2]` like a boss.  For example:

```
trait Foo { def foo: String }
trait Bar { def bar: String }

implicit def stringFoo(a: String) = new Foo { def foo = a + " sf" }
implicit def stringBar(a: String) = new Bar { def bar = a + " sb" }
implicit def intFoo(a: Int) = new Foo { def foo = a.toString + " if" }
implicit def intBar(a: Int) = new Bar { def bar = a.toString + " ib" }

val s1 = Seq[Foo & Bar]("hoho", 1)
val s2 = s1 flatMap (ab => Seq(ab.foo, ab.bar))
// equal to Seq("hoho sf", "hoho sb", "1 if", "1 ib")
```

The implicit conversions from `String` and `Int` to type `Foo & Bar` occur when the sequence is populated, and then the implicit conversions from `Foo & Bar` to `Foo` and `Bar` occur when calling `foobar.foo` and `foobar.bar`.

### The current ridiculous question(s):

1. Has anybody implemented this pattern anywhere before, or am I the first idiot to do it?
2. Is there a much simpler way of doing this that I've blindly missed?
3. If not, then how would I implement more general plumbing, such that I can write `Seq[Foo & Bar & Baz]`? This seems like a job for `HList`...
4. *Extra mega combo bonus:* in implementing the more general plumbing, can I constrain the types to be unique?  For example, I'd like to prohibit `Seq[Foo & Foo]`.

### The appendix of fails:

[My latest attempt (gist)](https://gist.github.com/2188596).  Not terrible, but there are two things I dislike there:

- The `Seq[All[A :: B :: C :: HNil]]` syntax (I want the `HList` stuff to be opaque, and prefer `Seq[A & B & C]`)
- The explicit type annotation (`abc[A].a`) required for conversion.  It seems like you can either have type inference or implicit conversions, but not both...  I couldn't figure out how to avoid it, anyhow.

Comment: This question is related to the "extra mega combo bonus": [enforce type difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference)

Comment: I'm not sure I see the connection between `HList` and what you're trying to do.... An HList is a list whose type maintains the type information about the constituent elements, whereas it sounds like you want to have a list wherein each constituent conforms to some fixed set of types.

Comment: @AaronNovstrup I'm trying to use something like `HList` as an arbitary-arity substitute for the fixed 2-arity `&[A, B]` class I defined. My goal is to have something that looks mostly like my `Seq[A & B]`, where the elements of the collection can be viewed as both `A` and `B` simultaneously, but again for an arbitrary number of types.

Comment: @AaronNovstrup ... although I'm wondering if it might be more natural to encode this with some technique more like Miles's [unboxed union type](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) rather than `HList`.

Comment: It's not really relevant to your question, but I just want to point out that `Seq[_ <: T]` is not the same as `Seq[T]`. `Seq[_ <: T]` is existential.

Comment: Would the trait (interface) model achieve the goal? http://www.scala-lang.org/node/126

Comment: @FlavorScape no, the goal is to avoid subtyping.

Comment: @mergeconflict you crazy kids and your functional languages.

Comment: To clarify what you actually want: You want a heterogeneous list that allows only types that are viewable as certain types?

Comment: @Kaito: I want to populate a standard data structure (e.g. `Seq`) with objects viewable as every member of a given set of types. See the `Seq[Foo & Bar]` example above. `HList` comes into play when attempting to generalize to more than two views.

Answer (score 1):

I can give a partial answer for the point 4. This can be obtained by applying a technique such as :

http://vpatryshev.blogspot.com/2012/03/miles-sabins-type-negation-in-practice.html