# Why don't impredicative types allow for heterogenous lists?

Tags: haskell, types

I've a short example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}

main = mapM_ print ([1 :: Int, "str", Just 5] :: [forall a. Show a => a])
```

This fails for two reasons (produces 4 errors, but 3 of them are the same for each element):

```
No instance for (Show (forall a. Show a => a))
  arising from a use of `print'
```

Which is very puzzling (and I don't understand it either), and the other one:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Int)
from the context (Show a)
  bound by a type expected by the context: Show a => a
  at main.cpp:5:18-42
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      a type expected by the context: Show a => a at main.cpp:5:18
In the expression: 1 :: Int
```

Which seems to rigidize the context to `Show a => a`. Why doesn't it work? Aren't impredicative types basically a gateway to this?

Comment: The `ImpredicativeTypes` extension doesn't really work. It's not really worth digging into any more details, I don't think.

Comment: @dfeuer I am partially aware of that; in fact [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3sotab/what_are_the_predominant_experimental_programming/cwza63a) prompted me to write this question. I still believe it can be answered *in principle*, that is, what would happen if we had a perfect GHC?

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10170083/752976)

Comment: `forall a. Show a => a` is also emphatically *not* an instance of `Show`. In fact, its only value is `undefined`. You're probably mixing it up with `exists a. Show a` (which isn't valid Haskell, of course).

Comment: What @AndrásKovács said. `1 :: Int` does not even have type `forall a. Show a => a`, so why would you expect `[1 :: Int, "str", Just 5]` to be able to have type `[forall a. Show a => a]` if the latter type were allowed?