# Tuples with different types

Tags: haskell

Is any way to have a list of pairs without the same types in Haskell and make a function traverse it. For example:

```
a = [(1, "uno"), (2, True), (3, 5)]
```

A want to apply a function depending on the type of the second value, something like a function that evaluates the combination of the pair `f :: [(Int, #)] -> [a].`

Comment: I don’t think this is currently possible without the `ImpredicativeTypes` extension, which currently [doesn’t really work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33741334/465378).

Comment: @AlexisKing `ImpredicativeTypes` won't help you here. Impredicativity allows you to parameterise types by `forall`-quantified types, eg to make a _homogeneous_ list of polymorphic functions. OP wants to build a _heterogeneous_ list of monomorphic tuples.

Comment: @jonaprieto What are you trying to achieve? The simplest way is to build a sum type and do runtime case analysis on the values: `a :: [(Int, Either Bool String)]`

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson after here the comments, I decide to use a sum type, because actually, I have six types. Then, yes, I'll do the case analysis.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Sure, but I wasn’t thinking directly. OP specified “a function depending on the type of the second value”, which could become a typeclass with a method, which could then be used in a `forall` quantification using `ImpredicativeTypes`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap the values in a sum-type. E.g.,

```
data StringOrBoolOrInt =
  StringOrBoolOrInt_String String |
  StringOrBoolOrInt_Bool Bool |
  StringOrBoolOrInt_Int Int

a :: [(Int, StringOrBoolOrInt)]
a =
  [
    (1, StringOrBoolOrInt_String "uno"),
    (2, StringOrBoolOrInt_Bool True),
    (3, StringOrBoolOrInt_Int 5)
  ]
```

Answer (score 7):

[To a first approximation](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/), no, this is not possible. Normalize the values first, e.g. by applying some class-polymorphic function to each of the second arguments, before putting them in the tuples.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, as given, this problem has no solution. But your real problem is that your data is not described by a list of tuples - by definition, a list is homogenous (all elements contain the same type) while your data is heterogenous.

If you want write a function depending on the type, you must store the type on the type level somehow.

Your example data is actually described by the type `Prod ((,) Integer) '[String, Bool, Integer]`, where `Prod` is the following type:

```
data Prod f (xs :: [a]) where 
  P0 :: Prod f '[] 
  (:>) :: f x -> Prod f xs -> Prod f (x ': xs) 

infixr 5 :>
```

or more generally `Prod ((,) Integer) xs` for some list of types `xs`.

Your example value is then

```
a = (1, "uno") :> (2, True) :> (3, 5) :> P0
```

You can branch on these types using the normal methods - i.e. a type class. Supposing one has such a class:

```
class HasFoo x where 
  foo :: x -> Integer 

instance HasFoo String where foo = fromIntegral . length 
instance HasFoo Bool where foo = fromIntegral . fromEnum 
instance HasFoo Integer where foo = id
```

you can apply such a `foo` function to every element of your product

```
type family All (c :: k -> Constraint) (xs :: [k]) :: Constraint where 
  All c '[] = () 
  All c (x ': xs) = (c x, All c xs) 

-- example operation: add everything 
fooProd :: All HasFoo xs 
        => Prod ((,) Integer) xs 
        -> Integer 
fooProd P0 = 0 
fooProd ((i, x) :> ps) = i + foo x + fooProd ps
```

This requires some GHC extensions, at least `TypeFamilies`, `GADTs`, `ConstraintKinds`, `DataKinds`, `PolyKinds`.